# Is it possible to use MAX with a condition?

Tags: postgresql, query

I have a **jobs** table that has two relevant fields `date_executed` and `user_id`. I was wondering if there's a way I can avoid joins or inline sql and just calculate both the last executed time, and the last executed time for a specific user in one simple query. I want to bee able to use MAX on everything, and a MAX on a subset of the results.

Example mock-up query. Line 3 has made-up syntax that's hopefully self-explanatory for what I want to do:

```sql
SELECT
    MAX(date_executed) as last_executed,
    MAX(date_executed, user_id = 'current-user-id') as last_executed_by_user
FROM
    jobs;
GROUP BY
    some_other_field
```

Comment: Look for [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm a bit rusty with PostgreSQL, but I believe the query below is ISO-compliant and so *should* work):

```
SELECT
    MAX( date_executed) as last_executed,
    MAX( CASE WHEN user_id = $userId THEN date_executed END ) AS last_executed_by_user
FROM
    jobs;
GROUP BY
    some_other_field
```

- `$userId` is a parameter you'll specify in your PostgreSQL client library.
- A `CASE WHEN x THEN y END` expression without an `ELSE` case will evaluate to `NULL` when `x` is false or `Unknown`.
- The `MAX` aggregate function only considers non-`NULL` values, therefore it only considers values in `jobs.date_executed` when `jobs.user_id = $userId`.

You can also use the `FILTER` clause to get the same result (thanks for the tip, [ypercubeᵀᴹ!](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9)):

```
SELECT
    MAX( date_executed) AS last_executed,
    MAX( date_executed ) FILTER ( WHERE user_id = $userId ) AS last_executed_by_user
FROM
    jobs;
GROUP BY
    some_other_field
```

Both queries will return `last_executed_by_user = NULL` if there are no rows where `user_id = $userId`.

Comment: It seems to me that `FILTER` is by far the superior way of doing this (I was experimenting with this last night). If you want to test your answers, you can always use the excellent [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c58fc8a23e398910651beba71d87134c) site.